# Differentiate the function $g(x)=(t^x)(x^t)$.

Tags: calculus

Let $t$ be a positive real number. Differentiate the function

> $$g(x)=t^x x^t.$$

Your answer should be an expression in $x$ and $t$.

came up with the answer

> $$(x/t)+(t/x)\ln(t^x)(x^t)=\ln(t^x)+\ln(x^t)=x\ln t+t\ln x .$$

and the derivative to that is $(x/t)+(t/x)$. Not sure if I've done it right.

Comment: Why did you take the natural log of everything?

Comment: Please make the effort to format your questions properly; help can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure just what you were doing; it looks as if you might have been trying to use logarithmic differentiation and getting a bit confused in the process. In any case there’s no need for anything fancy.

Since $g(x)$ is a product, your first step should be to use the product rule:

$$g'(x)=t^x(x^t)'+\left(t^x\right)'x^t\;,$$

where the primes indicate derivatives with respect to $x$. Differentiating $x^t$ is just a matter of using the power rule: $(x^t)'=tx^{t-1}$. Differentiating the exponential is like differentiating $e^x$, provided that you remember to compensate for the fact that $t$ isn’t (ncessarily) $e$: $(t^x)'=t^x\ln t$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
g'(x)&=t^x(tx^{t-1})+(t^x\ln t)x^t\\
&=t^{x+1}x^{t-1}+t^xx^t\ln t\;;
\end{align*}$$

if you like, you can pull out some common factors and write

$$g'(x)=t^xx^{t-1}\left(t+x\ln t\right)\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the product rule for differentiation, $$g'(x)=(t^x)'(x^t)+(t^x)(x^t)'=(t^x)(\ln t)(x^t)+(t^x)(t)(x^{t-1})=(t^x)(\ln t)(x^t)+t^{x+1}x^{t-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)= t^xx^t = e^{ln(t^xx^t)}
=e^{xln(t) + tln(x)}$

Now,

$g'(x)= \frac{d}{dx}e^{ln(t^xx^t)}$

$=\frac{d}{dx}e^{xln(t) + tln(x)}$

$= e^{xln(t) + tln(x)}.\frac{d}{dx}({xln(t) + tln(x)})$

$= e^{xln(t) + tln(x)}.(ln(t)+\frac{t}{x})$

$=t^xx^t.(ln(t)+\frac{t}{x})$

Answer (score 0):

Why not try logarithmic differentiation:

$$\ln\bigl((g(x)\bigr)=x\ln(t)+t\ln(x),$$
thus
$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\ln(t)+\frac{t}{x},$$
from which $g'$ is easily onbtained.

Michael